# DFS (depth first search) sequence of nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

I want to implement dfs for nodes that are of type `long` in Java.

My algorithm calculates correctly the number of nodes, and the number

of edges, but not the sequence of nodes. Could you please help me

modify my algorithm so I calculate the order in which the nodes are

visited, correctly?

This is my code:

```
private int getNumberOfNodes(long firstNode) {  
    List<Long> marked = new ArrayList<>();  //------------------------------------------->
    Stack<Long> stack = new Stack<Long>();  //step 1  Create/declare stack
    stack.push(firstNode);                  //Step 2 Put/push inside the first node
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {              //Repeat till stack is empty:
       Long node = stack.pop();             //Step 3 Extract the top node in the stack
       marked.add(node);                    //------------------------------------------->
       long[] neighbors = xgraph.getNeighborsOf(node); //Get neighbors
       if (neighbors.length % 2 == 0) {
           
       } else {
           numOfNodesWithOddDegree++;
       }
       int mnt = 0;
       for (long currentNode : neighbors) {
           if (!marked.contains(currentNode) && !stack.contains(currentNode) ) { //&& !stack.contains(currentNode)  
               stack.push(currentNode);

           } else {
               
           }
           if (!marked.contains(currentNode)) {
               numOfEdges++;
           }
       }
    }
    return marked.size(); //(int) Arrays.stream(neighbors).count();
}
```

Comment: You're pushing all neighbours of a node to a stack and then explore them. This is BFS, not DFS

Comment: How should I push them instead? Could you please post a code example?

Comment: Can you clarify with a small example graph, where this algorithm produces the wrong sequence? What does it give as sequence, and what was expected? Your function returns a number, so it is not clear to me where you verify the sequence of nodes.

Comment: @c95 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-search-or-dfs-for-a-graph/

Comment: Μy graph is undirected though

Comment: @AbhinavMathur is wrong, as OP is using stack, it is DFS as stack is FILO. the marked list will contain the sequence of the nodes visited.

Comment: Stack is indeed what you need for DFS. Please make your code [mre]. Include  hard coded data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you exam the `marked` list for the sequence.

As your graph is undirected, the sequence of traversals could be varied based on which neighbor you pushed into the stack first. which means the logic of your function:

```
 xgraph.getNeighborsOf(node)
```

could impact your sequence. see Vertex orderings from this wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

so my conclusion is: you may have a different traversal sequence, it does not mean your DFS is wrong, as long as it is Deep first search, it is ok to be a little bit different from the given answer.